# Vector field integral confusion with 2 points

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

There is a vector field $\underline{v}(x,y,z) := (zcos(x)-ysin(x),-z,y)$

There are 2 points $p := (0,1,0)$ and $q := (π, −1, 0)$

The first part is to evaluate $∫_{C_{pq}}\underline{v}·dr$ where $C_{pq}$ is the line from $p$ to $q$

At first I thought this would be the area of the triangles these two points form with the x axis in the x-y plane, but this would mean that the vector field equation isn't relevant and so I don't think that this is correct.

I tried parameterising the equation of the line pq and got $x = πt, y = 1-2t$ and $z = 0$ and then going on to attempt to integrate $∫_{C_{pq}}\underline{v}(p(t))·p(t)dt$ where $p(t)$ is the parameterisation of the line. This however results in $∫πtsin(πt)(1-2t)dt$ which is not a nice integral and I am not sure about the t values(edit: I think it would be 0<=t<=1 and I get $(-π^2 + 8)/π^2$ . I know this is supposed to be simple, but I don't know what I am missing.

The second part is to evaluate the same integral but instead of a line it is the curve from $p$ to $q$ parameterised by $p(t) := (t, cos(t), sin(t))$ with $0 ≤ t ≤ π$. For this I tried the same method as I did for the first part, but obviously I already have the parameterised version of the curve so it was much easier just to sub it in, and I get the integral:

$∫_0^π0dt = 0$

Which I think is correct.

The last part of the question asks if $\underline{v}$ is conservative. I know that if, for all closed curves, $∮\underline{v} · dr = 0$, then it is conservative but I don't know how I would prove if it is or isn't.

Comment: There’s a more fundamental definition of a conservative vector field that you should be using. As for the two line integrals, the integrand should be $v(p(t))\cdot p'(t)\,dt$. I.e., $dr\ne p(t)\,dt$. You forgot to differentiate.

Comment: Thanks for your help, now that I have done it with the derivative of the parametrisation, I get 0 for the first integral and π for the second. My understanding of of what this means is that since these two are not the same, it means that changing the path between the same 2 points changes the value of the integral so v is not conservative.